# Command prompt npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm, command

There is some problem with my npm package. My node is perfectly installed. I checked through `node -v` cmd immediately spits out the version, but when I `npm -v` I get the following error

[image]

However, I thought it won't be a problem for installing packages. But I was wrong I get the following error. Please see the error log below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj4Wl.png]

Comment: Please don't share error messages as images

Comment: Yes, please change your images to blocks of formatted text. Images containing text are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and thus make it harder for people to help.

Comment: The general error ("not recognized as an internal or external command") is a duplicate anyway - please search for it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your command `npm -v` is executed and it returned you the version as **5.6.0**.

The issue here is of WINDOWS path variable.

It is not related to NPM and can be solve by following detailed steps from here:

[Link](https://ginesys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PUB/pages/9928717/command+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command+operable+program+or+batch+file+-+Error+message+is+shown+while+executing+a+Windows+command+through+command+prompt+cmd+or+an+executable+program)